# Count warning messages in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, error-handling, warnings

I'm using `gmdistribution.fit` in a loop for about `100,000` data each has `250` samples.

When I run my script I get warnings,

```
Warning: Failed to converge in 100 iterations for gmdistribution
with 2 components 
> In @gmdistribution\private\gmcluster at 183
  In gmdistribution.fit at 174
```

Is there a way to count the warnings (something like `catch`) so I could know how many of them didn't converge?

This is a general question of how to count the warning messages, the `GMM` is just an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the command you are working with only outputs a single warning each time you call it, you could use this:

```
warningCounter = containers.Map();
while(youComputeStuff)
    functionThatGivesASingleWarning();
    [msgstr, msgid] = lastwarn;
    lastwarn(''); % Reset lastwarn
    if ~isempty(msgstr);
        if isKey(warningCounter, msgstr)
            warningCounter(msgstr) = warningCounter(msgstr)+1;
        else
            warningCounter(msgstr) = 1;
        end
    end
end
disp([warningCounter.keys; warningCounter.values])
```

If you can't have this kind of control flow, because your function can give multiple warnings on each call, you could consider overriding the built-in `warning` and use some global counting variable.